# Comment les étiquettes partagent-elles nos questions avec d'autres sites SE ? How do our tags share Qs on other stacks?

Tags: discussion, tags, site-promotion

Et si on parlait promotion ?

Après avoir partagé la question [Why does everyone in The Lord of the Rings use "vous" ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/51116/1893) sur [SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/).SE tchat (réponse : that's awesome), puis trois heures plus tard HNQ, dix heures plus tard sur tweeter*, bref c'est Tolkien, je me demande combien d'autres questions restent cantonnées sur FSE faute d'étiquettes partagées.

D'abord c'est une bonne question **bien recherchée** qui a trait à des domaines culturels variés, plusieurs langues, la traduction, la littérature et le cinéma. Les questions à propos du choix entre tutoiement et vouvoiement ne sont pas nouvelles au niveau de l'apprentissage mais l'analyse est nuancée dans ce cas, c'est dynamique.  De bonnes réponses sont très possibles et il y en a déjà trois.  Les commentaires peuvent presque mériter une salle de tchat...et c'est formidable.

Nous, on voit les questions marquées [[French]] mais est-ce qu'il y a des étiquettes que nous partageons avec d'autres sites?  Comme on n'a pas besoin d'étiquette [LoTR] est-ce qu'il y a d'autres logiciels pour partager ou faire ce genre de promotion ? Il était facile de le mettre sur SF&F et comme c'est Tolkien et les langues ça attire déjà beaucoup de monde mais ce n'est pas automatisé.  Que faire ?

---

What about some site promotion?

After I shared a link to the above question on SF&F chat (reply: that's awesome) -- three hours later, it went HNQ, ten hours later it was tweeted*, that's Tolkien for you -- I had to wonder how many questions we might have that go unnoticed by other SE sites as a result of tags.

First, it's a good question because it's **well researched** and it can be answered.  It involves cultural usage, language comparisons, literature, cinéma, and translation.  The comments might get close to needing their own chatroom, and that's a good thing in this case.  Even if the French is pretty straightforward, the tu/vous questions being nothing new to learners, the breakdown is nuanced here and it's dynamic.

It was easy enough to hop over to the chat in SF&F to share it; it's Tolkien (and languages), so already interesting to a lot of people, but it's not a program.  Here we see questions from other stacks tagged [[French]] pop up automatically in chat, but what are we sharing?  Since we don't have or need a [LoTR] tag, what are other ways to use tags for site promotion? What else?

*autant pour Twitter, ~100 followers

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of discussion

This [feed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?user=-2&q=French) shows other SE sites that have tagged [French] or use the word French including some of our own.

Do any of these strike anyone as promotion inspiring in chat?  Are any useful for possibilities of exchanging helpful robot feeds?  Travel seems the least related to language, but there is a recent literature question.

Otherwise I'll note the feed robots we receive in chat: Linguistics, EL&U, and Latin coming this way plus our own bountied questions and meta questions.

We are reciprocal with Latin.SE.

Thoughts on Literature?  Linguistics?

As most of you know, it would just pop up in chat, not post or cross-post to the main.